# AngularJS how to use $q in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, q

I am new at AngularJs and very new at Typescript.
I included Typescript in my AngularJs project but couldn't handle a service where i return a $q(function(){...})

my code looks like:

```
  function foo(request, monitor, currentMonitorPropertys) {
    var currentChart;
    return $q(function (resolve) {
        $http(request).success(function (chartResponse) {
            ...
            resolve(monitor);
        }).error(function(response){
            ...
        });
    });
```

I work with VS2013(TypeScript), if i implement this method like above, there comes an compilererror: Value of type 'IQService' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?

So how could I implement the function with Typescript.
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: This looks like it may be a bug in the angular d.ts contract. Can you try it with `return new $q(functon (resolve) {` and see if it works?

Comment: this won't work, i can not generate a new $q. 
My first idea was to return $q(function(resolve){ ... 
(with the given $q-service)
but the compiler wasn't happy with that. 

i don't know how to handle the new implementation, where i give the $q-service a function, so i used the old implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to return a promise... `$http` returns a promise with each of its ajax calls, `$timeout` also returns a promise.

That being said you want to return a promise based upon something other than a scheduled event (`$timeout`, `$interval`) via `$q` you can do this...

```
// assume $q is injected into your service/controller/factory
// create a defer object
var defer = $q.defer();
// do something...
if (doSomething()){
  defer.resolve(); //something went right
else {
  defer.reject(); //something went wrong
}
//make sure you return out the promise, so the consumer can act upon it.
return defer.promise;
```

Also, `$q` has some nice helper methods to return a promise that you can use when you stub out some logic;

```
// this will a promise that will resolve with the value provided
return $q.when({some: 'result'});

// this will return a promise that will reject with the error specified
return $q.reject('some error message');
```

Comment: Thank you, and all other who commented. 

It seems like the old implementation of the service will work with VS2013 and typescript.

Answer (score 0):

`$q` isn't a function but a service. If you want a defer, you can use the following code for example:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();

$http(request).success(function (chartResponse) {
        deferred.resolve(monitor);
    }).error(function(response){
        deferred.reject(response);
    });

// return promise
return deferred.promise;
```

What you can keep in mind if you don't do anything else, you can just return the `$http` call, because it is a promise itself:

```
return $http(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're using `$http` (that already returns a promise) why not returning this promise directly? Simpler and faster.

```
function foo(request, monitor, currentMonitorPropertys) {
  var currentChart;
  return $http(request).then(function (chartResponse) {
      //...
      return monitor;
  });
});
```

Then when consuming this service you could manage `success` and `error` from there, which makes for a tidier implementation:

```
// for ex. in a controller

foo().then(mySuccessCallback)
     .catch(myErrorHandler)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to defer $q before resolve it This is code try this one

---

```
(function retriveDemoJsonData(){

    angular.module('myApp').factory('actionData', function ($q, $http) {

        var data={};
        data.actionDataJson = function(id){
           //The original business logic will apply based on URL Param ID
```

> ```
> var defObj = $q.defer();
>             $http.get('demodata.json')
>                 .then(function(res){
>                      defObj.resolve(res.data[0]);
>                 });
>             return defObj.promise;
> ```

```
        }
        return data;
    });

})();
```

----------+
I hope this will help you......